# Upgrade PC to Use as CentOS Server?

Tags: nas, centos-7

Currently I have Some Sites and One Mobile App
Hosted in Godaddy.com Shared Business Hosting Established Plan:
4 Virtually Allocated CPU Core
16GB RAM
240GB Storage

Everything works fine but i want to turn my own PC into CentOS Server taking advantage of My Fiber Optic High Speed Internet Connection which currenlty have so i need to upgrade my PC to match the Basic Specifications base on current Hosting Specifications Also make a count that i need USE 20TB HDD include One Samsung 970 PRO SSD 1TB - M.2 NVMe So i need a Recommendation to Upgrade the PC Base on those Specifications ( Preferable that this Specifications can be used as NAS System too ).

My Current Computer Specifications:
ASUS Maximus VIII Hero (Intel Z170)Intel® Core™ i7-6700K Processor (8M Cache, up to 4.20 GHz)Memory X 4:* Kingston HyperX Predator 32GB Kit 3000MHz DDR4 (2 x 16GB)

- G-Skill Ripjaws V F4-3200C16D-16GVRB DDR4 (2 x 8GB)
  NVIDIA Quadro P2000 5GB GDDR5Hard Disk X 5:* Samsung SSD 840 EVO 1TB
- Seagate ST3000DM001-1CH166 3TB
- Seagate ST2000DM001-1CH164 2TB
- Western Digital Black WD3003FZEX-00Z4Sa0 3TB
- Western Digital Red 8TB NAS Hard Disk Drive WD80EFZX
  Corsair AX760 ATXObsidian Series™ 650D Mid-Tower Case

Comment: Professional hosting usually provides two geo locations, each equipped with fail over configuration, UPS backed up servers and network infrastructure ...

Comment: I only want to achive basic things in term of Hardware only nothing more